# What are the (dis)advantages of a constant declared in an anonymous namespace vs a function-scope static constant?

Tags: c++, static, namespaces, constants

I want to define a function that, when given an integer, will return a string. Like this:

```
# Pseudocode
function get_string(i)
  return my_string_array[i]
end
```

The strings will be hard coded into the application. The function prototype is declared in a header file:

```
// header.h
const std::string &get_string(const int i);
```

The way I see it, I have two options for declaring the hard-coded strings.

**Option #1: Declare a static variable in `get_string`**

```
// source.cpp
const std::string &get_string(const int i)
{
    static const std::string values[] = {
        std::string("foo"),
        std::string("bar"),
        std::string("baz"),
    };

    // Assume bounds checking is performed on i.

    return values[i];
}
```

**Option #2: Declare global constant in an anonymous namespace**

```
// source.cpp
namespace
{
    const std::string values[] = {
        std::string("foo"),
        std::string("bar"),
        std::string("baz"),
    };
}

const std::string &get_string(const int i)
{
    // Assume bounds checking is performed on i.
    return values[i];
}
```

**For this limited use-case, are these declarations functionally equivalent? Does the program treat static constants in functions differently from globally declared constants or constants declared in anonymous namespaces?**

I'm aware of the obvious accessibility differences (i.e. constant declared in local namespace is available globally to all functions defined in the same translation unit), but that can be chalked up as an advantage either way depending on the scenario, so for the purposes of this question this difference can be omitted.

Comment: The only difference I could think of is that globals are initialized at the start of the program before `main` is entered; while function statics are initialized only when the function is first called. In your case, the distinction probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Define it inside the function itself, if nobody else uses it directly (which nobody should do, ideally, otherwise, there is no purpose of the function itself). Apart from that, you must check `i` for out-of-range value, before accessing the element.

Comment: @Nawaz - Fear not, bounds checking would be performed for sure :-)

Comment: Depending on your use case, if `i` is known at compile time, you could make `get_string` a template function taking `i` as a template parameter and use template specialization to return the appropriate string. You probably determine `i` at runtime so maybe this won't work, just throwing out options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings defined as static array inside your get_string function will be constructed on the first `get_string` call, while strings in global namespace will be constructed on application start.

So the problems that might arrise are different for both aproaches. For example if you go with defining strings at global scope then you should not use it before your `main` is executed, otherwise you never know if they got constructed. If you go with static construction inside `get_string` you may encounter threading problems at least until c++11, after that magic statics should fix this for you.

Why dont you put them inside `const char*` global array?

[edit]

Global array is not the right way to do it, as I suggested above. Another thing for you to consider is to go with option 1, but instead of array of strings create array of `const char*` string literals. Array of std::string object's will duplicate your string literals. You would have to probably also return `const char*` - so maybe thats not what you want.

Comment: *Why dont you put them inside const char\* global array?* ..Why `const char*` exactly? Why *global* exactly?

Comment: I thought that would fix the 'static initialization order fiasco' problem, also I meant static array of 'const char*'.

Comment: I agree that going with `Option #1` should be recomended.

Comment: *"static initialization order fiasco"* has nothing to with elements being `std::string`, and thus if at all it is going to show up in this case, it cannot be fixed by replacing `std::string` with `const char*`.

Comment: uh, right - such global array would still have to be assigned during initialization.